# How to check all messages that push to many users (in one time) really success to all users?

Tags: line, chatbot, line-api

Same the title, I want to detect if have some response fail then I will code to resent a message again.

I use line API thanks

Comment: are you using multicast to send messages to all users?

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya Yes

Comment: you will get success only when everyone get messages, as far as i know